# Test Role based authorization API of ASP.NET Core Identity framework using postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am developing the APIs for an application in .NET 6. I am using ASP.NET Core Identity framework for authentication and authorization. The front-end of the application is in React.
I have "Admin" role in my application and as per Identity framework specifications this role is stored in the "AspNetRoles" table. I have assigned a user to this role and there is a corresponding entry in the "AspNetUserRoles". For applying Role based authorization on my Administrative controller, I have added `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` on my controller.

I was following a tutorial, the tutorial was developed in ASP.NET Core MVC (front-end was in Razor). In the tutorial, `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` works perfectly fine i.e. if a user is associated with "Admin" role, only then he will be able to access the Administrative controller else he will be redirected to Access Denied page.

I want to test this API using postman but I am unable to find out what should be passed in the `Authorization` header. I have read multiple articles on this and how this thing is working with MVC. From all my research, I find out that Identity framework and .NET Core is handling all of this internally but, I am pretty sure that I am lagging somewhere and there should be a way to test the role based authorization APIs of Identity framework through postman.

I have these nuget packages installed in the project. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore (6.0.10)`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (6.0.10)`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (6.0.10)`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (6.0.10)`.

My program.cs contains,

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

My controller code is,

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AdministrationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public AdministrationController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateRole")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole (CreateRoleModel roleModel)
    {
        IdentityRole ir = new IdentityRole { Name = roleModel.RoleName };

        IdentityResult result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(ir);

        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Ok("Role created successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Error in creating role");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I call "CreateRole" API from postman and check if only the users associated with the Admin role can access it and others cannot. I believe there should be a token which needs to be passed in the Authorization header but, I am unable to get that how this token is getting generated. Similarly, when this API will be called from the React app, React app would have to send some information or Authorization in the header of the request. How can I get that information in the Identity framework? I believe there would be something at the login time of the user.

Any help on this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: As you know identity send the `userClaim` and based on that `user role and action` selected so certainly you cannot do that using postman. You must implement `jwt` token controller only then can call anything from postman passing the token.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, I am able to call the Role based API from swagger UI. Identity framework by default uses cookie for authentication and authorization. So, when I logged in from the swagger UI by calling the Login API, a cookie was generated and then I called the CreateRole API from the swagger UI and I was able to access it because the cookie which was generated at the login time was sent with the CreateRole request and from that cookie Authorization attribute worked. That's my understanding at the moment, if there is something wrong or anything I am missing, you can add to that.

Comment: Yes, using cookie it can be done, likewise, you could do same from postman as well.